# Block RAM on Bidirection Bus

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, synthesis

I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to connect the core generated Block RAM of a Xilinx Spartan 6 FPGA up to a bidirectional data bus. All the examples I can find say to just use the in and out data ports individually, but in my case I am forced to use it as a bidirectional data bus.

I am using VHDL.

The generated component has the following definition:

```
COMPONENT ram
    PORT (
       clka  : IN STD_LOGIC;
       wea   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
       addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
       dina  : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
       douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;
```

Which is instantiated as follows:

```
ram1 : ram
  PORT MAP (
    clka => clk,
    wea => r_w,
    addra => addr,
    dina => din,
    douta => dout
  );
```

Can someone show me a process block that will connect `dina` and `douta` to an `inout` port called `data`?

I tried the following, with 0% success:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if r_w = "1" then
      -- Write
      din <= data;
      dout <= temp;
    else
      -- Read
      din <= (others => 'Z');
      data <= dout;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: What are `din` and `dout` here? Signals?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see them in the port mapping there. Never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's important to understand that internally to a modern FPGA (such as the Xilinx Spartan-6 you are talking about), there is not *really* any true bidirectional routing. Real bidirectional/tristate signals can only be used on I/O pins. Internal bidirectional/tristate signals can be emulated, but this is generally only done for interfacing with legacy HDL, not for anything new.

Now, regardless of whether there was true tristate or not, in order to hook up unidirectional `dina` and `douta` to the a "bidirectional" `data`, you need some signal to control when the memory is driving or not. Since we have short names already, let's just call it `oe` for "output enable". This signal will need to be controlled by your design in a way that make sense.

Given that, you can turn your two unidirectional signals in different directions plus your output enable direction selector into a logically bidirectional data bus with the following concurrent code (***not*** in a process):

```
dina <= data;
data <= douta when oe = '1' else (others => 'Z');
```

Comment: Might this have the effect of routing the data output of the `ram` entity back to its input? This might be okay though...

Comment: Yes, the RAM's output will always route back to it's input when the output is driving. But that's exactly what you've asked for with a bidirectional bus! =) The RAM's output is irrelevent when oe = '0'.

Comment: Well it depends on the context here, but it's not *necessarily* what someone would want. I've had components interfacing to a bidirectional port that needed the extra layer of indirection to avoid one port driving another. But I agree that it's probably not a problem here :)

Comment: @detly I'm not sure what you're saying is an alterative, really. There are only two options. Either dina and douta are connected together to a bidirection signal, in which case dina will *always* get the value of douta when douta is driving, or you keep dina and douta separate, which means they are not connected together to a bidirectional signal (which, yes, is a much better way to do it, but not what the questioner asked for).

Comment: What I meant was that `dina` and `douta` would be connected to a signal (which is not directional at all), and that signal would be selectively connected to the bidirectional port.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The reason I'm stuck with this is I'm trying to take an old 1980's discrete logic board and put it all within an FPGA. While I could change everything to have two data buses instead of one, I'm trying to keep it true to its original form, as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the `if r_w = "1"` block, you appear to be trying to drive to your `dout` signal, which should be driven by the port `douta`. That might explain one problem (unless `temp` is all 'Z's).

Caveat for the following: I don't have anything to test this on right now, so it's all off the top of my head. Let me know if it's not helpful!

I don't think that a synchronous process is the best way to approach this. It's been a while since I've needed to do this, but here's what I think you need. Note that it's not a process, it goes right in the architecture.

```
din <= data when (r_w = '1') else (others => 'Z');
data <= dout when (r_w = '0') else (others => 'Z');
```

Explanation: when signals are being driven (or assigned to) by multiple sources, all but one of them must be 'Z'. The second line sets `data` to be driven by 'Z' — but this actually "frees it up" (from the point of view of the resolver) to be driven by the port.

If you do need this to be synchronous, this should be trivial to adapt — but remember that `'0'` and `'1'` aren't the only possible cases for `std_logic`, so think about an `else` clause or `others` in a `case` block!